# Nuxt3 Generate - Wait for async data when pre-rendering

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

```
<template>
    <article class="post" v-if="post">
        <section
            v-html="post.content"
        ></section>
    </article>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
const route = useRoute();
const post = await $fetch(`/api/post/${route.params.handle}`).catch(() => {});
</script>
```

I am wanting `npm run generate` to wait for `$fetch` so that `post.content` will be rendered in the HTML, instead of added to the page after load. I can't for the life of me figure out any way to do this. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Vue's reactivity system to conditionally render the content when it is available.

```
  <article class="post" v-if="post">
    <section v-if="post.content" v-html="post.content"></section>
  </article>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const route = useRoute();
const post = ref(null);

(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await $fetch(`/api/post/${route.params.handle}`);
    post.value = response.data; // Assuming your data is in response.data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
</script>
```

Comment: This may work, however how does it satisfies OP's pre-render need? This potentially sends an empty layout to the user, then content appears a moment later. That is the opposite of pre-render.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out using the composition API. I used the `onServerPrefetch` lifecycle hook to grab the data.

```
async function fetchData() {
    return await $fetch(`/api/post/${route.params.handle}`);
}

onServerPrefetch(() => {
    return new Promise(async (res) => {
        post.value = await fetchData();
        res("");
    });
});
```

The key is the promise. The promise makes `onServerPrefetch` wait for the data to be fetched.

Comment: If using Nuxt, then might be better to leverage `useAsyncData`.